# When does the "fat arrow" (=>) bind to "this" instance

Tags: coffeescript, this, arrow-functions

The fat arrow can be used in different settings but it somehow doesn't
always bind to the instance I want.

Comment: See also this discussion and my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17431824/517371

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fat arrow binds at 3 occasions

1. when declaring a method
2. when declaring a function within a method
3. when declaring a function in global context

#### 1. When declaring a method

When the Coffeescript compiler encouters the following syntactical pattern
within a class declaration

```
class A
    somemethod: (paramlist) =>
```

This will yield the following code within the constructor of class A

```
this.somemethod = __bind(this.somemethod, this);
```

That is the definition for that instance is overwriting the initial assignment
with a bound version of the function

#### 2. When declaring a function within a method

When you define a function with a fat arrow within a method the Coffeescript compiler
automatically creates a closure and and shadows **this** of the outer method into the variable
**_this**. Any reference to **@** within the inner function will use the variable **_this**
in the generated javascript code

```
somemethod: ->
   => @someCall()
```

And this is the corresponding Javascript

```
A.prototype.somemethod = function() {
    //_this references this
    var _this = this;
    return function() {
        //and _this is now used within the inner function
        return _this.someCall();
    };
};
```

A definition of a function without the fat arrow doesn't create that closure for you.

#### 3. When declaring a function in global context

If you define a free floating function (meaning as a method in a class and not within another function/method) just like this

```
foo = => @bar
```

Then the corresponding Javascript will look like this

```
var foo,
  _this = this;

foo = function() {
    return _this.bar;
};
```

The interesting thing here again is that *this* is being assigned to _*this* which enables the definition of *foo* to close over _*this*.

The important part however is that *this* is always the global context of your execution environment. If you are in the browser it will be the window object. If you are running node.js it will be the module you are just running.

**Warning:** You shouldn't define any function accessing your global context anyway. This calls for trouble.