# how to refer the parent object in an event handler using Coffeescript fat arrow

Tags: coffeescript, arrow-functions

Hi I'm new to Js and Coffeescript, here's a situation I feel difficult to refer the property of parent object which is `App` in the following example

```
App =
  init: ->
    this.foo = 'bar'
    this.bindEvent()
  bindEvent: ->  
    $('#test').click(this.show)
  show: ->
    alert this.foo

App.init()
```

I think the fat arrow may do the trick but once I've changed to `show: =>`, `this` in the context of `show` method refers to the window object, instead of `App` object that I want to 
. Anybody can tell me how to do it right?

http://jsfiddle.net/kZpHX/

Comment: Have a look of this answer for a discussion of the fat arrow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184209/when-does-the-fat-arrow-bind-to-this-instance/13184211#13184211 to se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define your `show` function, `@` (AKA `this`) actually is `window` so

```
show: => console.log(@)
```

will bind `show` to `window`. The problem is that you're simply defining an object so there isn't anything to bind to: you aren't defining a class so `this` is `window`. You could refer to `App` explicitly like this:

```
App =
  #...
  show: -> alert(App.foo)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3sRVh/

The `this.foo` in `init` will do the right thing because saying `App.init()` sets up the expected `this`.

You could also hook up the desired `this` manually:

```
bindEvent: ->
  $('#test').click => @show()

# or
bindEvent: ->
  _this = @ # JavaScript style
  $('#test').click -> _this.show()
```

Demos: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/byL45/, http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/MT8fG/

Or you could create a class for your App instead:

```
class App
  constructor: ->
    @foo = 'bar'
    @bindEvent()
  bindEvent: ->  
    $('#test').click(@show)
  show: =>
    console.log(@foo)

new App
```

That way your `show: =>` will behave the way you expect it to.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/byatH/