# Why does the fat-arrow not bind to the current environment in loop comprehensions?

Tags: javascript, loops, binding, coffeescript, list-comprehension

If I compile this CoffeeScript:

```
    funcs = ((=> console.log i) for i in [0..2])                                                                                                                                                                                          

    funcs[0]()  // Prints 3
    funcs[1]()  // Prints 3
    funcs[2]()  // Prints 3
```

it produces this JavaScript:

```
    (function() {
      var funcs, i;

      funcs = (function() {
        var _i, _results,
          _this = this;
        _results = [];
        for (i = _i = 0; _i <= 3; i = ++_i) {
          _results.push(function() {
            return console.log(i);
          });
        }
        return _results;
      }).call(this);

      funcs[0]();

      funcs[1]();

      funcs[2]();

      funcs[3]();

    }).call(this);
```

I would think it would instead have:

```
          _results.push((function(i) {
             return function() {
              return console.log(i);
          }})(i));
```

Could someone explain why it's not doing that?

Comment: I think you have to do that explicitly: `((j) -> console.log j) for i in [0..2]`.

Comment: For more insight about the fat arrow have look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184209/when-does-the-fat-arrow-bind-to-this-instance?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Fat arrow binds `this` lexically, not every variable.
Use `do` to capture variables using an IIFE.

```
funcs =
  for i in [0..2]
    do (i) ->
      -> console.log i
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how closures work. You get a closure when you return a function from another function scope:

```
var closure = (function(i) {
    return function() {
        console.log(i);
    };
})(i);
```

This can be achieved via this ugly CoffeeScript (no need for a fat arrow here):

```
funcs = ((do (j=i) -> -> console.log j) for i in [0..2])
```

I'd recommend to not write this as a single line though.

Comment: You must have typed this before my edit.  My post had a mistake.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Nick Okay, the first bit is obsolete now. The CoffeeScript is however still a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after looking at the CoffeeScript documentation, I believe I've answered my own question.  `=>` only binds the function to the current value of `this`.  I had mistakenly assumed it bound all variables to their current value.

...although it would be neat if it had a feature like that.  Maybe `->>`?

Answer (score 0):

When you convert that coffee to javascript, you're getting a function that IS binding the scope. The problem is that:

```
funcs = (function() {
    var _i, _results,
      _this = this;
    _results = [];
    for (i = _i = 0; _i <= 3; i = ++_i) {
      _results.push(function() {
        return console.log(i);
      });
    }
    return _results;
  }).call(this);
```

in there, the variable i is bound, but by the time you call the function the value is 3, and remains in 3 every time you call the function.

Comment: I realize it does that.  But my question was about the fat-arrow's binding of the current scope on a per-function basis.  It basically comes down to the fact that it only binds the current value of `this`.

Comment: Ok, so again, it IS binding the scope (meaning that the i variable you get is the same everywhere), but it is not binding the value (precisely because it is binding the scope). What you would need is a fresh variable (not bound) in each of the scopes.

Comment: Right... I'm not challenging that.  I'm not sure where the confusion lies.

Comment: Okay, I guess I was loose with my wording.  Instead of "current scope" I should have said "the values of the current scope".